# Neutral line has 2.3v

Tags: wiring, voltage

I have a RV and I plugged into shore power for the first time the other day and noticed the plug has a test light that says if the wiring is good. It lit up saying my N and L were reversed.

I checked all the wires and everything is wired correctly. I then checked it with a multimeter and its wired correctly. I then plugged the trailer into another outlet on a different leg I don't know if its L1 or L2 but its the opposite leg the other outlet is on, and the plug lit up as good to go.

So then I checked the voltage on that one and compared it to the other outlet. The one that's "good" has a 121v hot and 0.2v neutral the "bad" one has 117v hot and 2.3v neutral. All of the measurements were to ground.

Originally I was thinking the RV plug was bad but now I think it's something wrong with my house wiring. Any ideas why I have so much power on my N wire but only on the one and not on the other?

Comment: Those low readings might be phantom voltage, depending on the meter.  Picking up some voltage just by being near the hot.  Neutral to ground should read 0v in perfect conditions.

Comment: yes but why would one outlet be 2v and another outlet be almost 0v? all N wires come off the same bar.

Comment: Could be caused by voltage drop  by a load on one of the legs.   2V is not a lot of power.

Answer (score 4):

Check some other receptacles around the house on *different* circuits. If they show similar results - 1/2 good, 1/2 not so good, then the problem is in your panel, possibly with the neutral/ground bond or one of the incoming hot wires. (Do **NOT** try to do anything with that incoming hot wire unless you really, *really*, **really** know what you are doing and have the right safety equipment.)

If receptacles around the house show consistent 119V - 121V on both legs then the problem is in the receptacle with the bad reading or someplace in that circuit between receptacle and panel. Check every connection in that circuit. Pay particular attention to backstabs (move to screws), loose wire nuts and any signs of heat damage.

Answer (score 2):

N and L reverse is very serious as it could result in "hot skin".  Still, those "3-light tester" type things are very dodgy in terms of their estimate of what the lights mean.

> Any ideas why i have so much voltage on my N wire but only on the one and not on the other?

Voltage drop boils down to

- size of wires
- length of wires
- amps actually being drawn by loads.

And classically with RV connections you are dealing with extraordinarily long wires, often extension cords which are under-sized wires compared to in-wall wiring of the same ampacity (because extension cords cool better than wires buried in wall insulation).

So an RV is a perfect storm for high voltage drop, especially if it's connected via ad-hoc connections to normal 120V/15A plugs instead of dedicated 120V/30A or 240V/50A connections.

For instance if you have 100' of wire on a 15A circuit, mostly #14 in-wall wires and some #16 extension cords wires, you may have 5 volts of *voltage drop*.  **Voltage drop affects hot and neutral wires in equal proportion**.  That means 2.5V of drop on a hot wire and 2.5V of drop on the neutral wire.

*What does "voltage drop on the neutral" look like, exactly?*  It looks like the neutral rising *Above* 0 volts compared to ground.  The neutral is suffering voltage drop, the ground is not.  It's rather like a beam-type torque wrench - the heavy beam is bending, but the little bar that holds the indicator needle is not bending.

So yes, if your house reads 119V at the panel, and you have 5V voltage drop to the RV, expect to see 116.5V hot-ground and 2.5V neutral-ground at the RV.

If it's different on a different circuit, it maybe because you have different loads turned on - **or more likely, ground is broken on that circuit**.  I could see a missing ground reading as a N-L reverse.

Comment: The cord to the trailer is 10ft and is made for 30A so it's oversized for the 15A outlet I plugged it into. Also it reads one outlet as fine and another outlet as not fine but both outlets are wired correctly. And I'm not reading the voltage at the trailer I'm reading it at the outlet in the house that I plugged the trailer into. Also both outlets are within the same room as the breaker box so I'm inclined to believe they don't have very long runs.

Comment: @rasmukri Well that blows that theory.  Might be time for a health check of your Grounding Electrode System, and you neutral-ground bond.  Because that close to the panel it should be <0.5 volts.